# Sort query result random but with a certain rules (usort)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, usort

I'm getting an array ( mysql_fetch_assoc() ) of rooms as the result of a mysql query. I want to order this array 'randomly' but with one rule. Each room number can not be more than 2 higher or lower than the next.

Now I assume I should use usort to do this but I can't seem to figure it out. I've looked at a number of questions and explanations of usort but I simply can't get it right. I'm sure this can't be as difficult as I'm currently experiencing it to be...

This is what I'm trying right now.

```
shuffle($room_array);

function cmp($a, $b){
    if ($a["room"] == $b["room"] || $a["room"]+2 == $b["room"]|| $a["room"]+1 == $b["room"]|| $a["room"]-2 == $b["room"]|| $a["room"]-1 == $b["room"]){
   return 1;
   }else return 0;
}

usort($room_array, "cmp");
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function cmp ($a, $b){
    return $b - $a; 
}
usort($room_array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Tried that with $b['room'] and a['room'] but to no avail. I have three arrays in the list. One with room 1, 3 or 5. That means I should get 1-3-5, 3-1-5 or 5-3-1,... However I still get 5-1-3 or 3-1-5 occasionally, so with a wider gap than 2.

Comment: That does indeed put them in a correct order but they're always descending now (5-3-1). I would like the order to be random so that 1-3-5 can also occur or other variations when I expand the database.

Comment: @Jorgos `3-1-5` here 1-5 diff is more that 2, what for this?

Comment: True, that's a mistake. I guess the only options for these three are 1-3-5  and 5-3-1. But I need something that will scale to more values and does it randomly each time.

Comment: @Jorgos actually in context of sorting either descending/ascending.